# Using systemd timer to shut down and start service

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have created a ServiceName.service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceName Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/<scriptName>.sh
```

And I have create a ServiceName.timer file.

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceName timer to start weekly

[Timer]
#reboot
OnBootSec=1min
#weekly
OnUnitActiveSec=1w
Unit=ServiceName.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The .sh file starts a webpage and a search with new results for the webpage that needs to be accessible for a week, and then perform a new search.

The scripts starts on boot, so that part works.
But it seems that the script has to shutdown the service first before the timer function works. I have no clue on how to do that.

Comment: You might need to set `Type=oneshot` on the service.

Comment: If you use Type=oneshot never add RemainAfterExit=true because .timer unit won't start an already started service https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unix & LinuxStackExchange.

First, you probably want  `After=network-online.target` to make sure the network is fully up.

Second, you must `systemctl enable ServiceName.timer` so that the timer will get started at boot. Did you do that? Use `systemctl list-timers` to check to see which are running.

Third, update your timer file to use `WantedBy=timers.target` which is the recommended target.